# Have a Winforms ComboBox derived control which bombs VS 2013 designer

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, derived-class

I had inherited the ComboBox winforms control. 
In the first trial, I added some properties, and the designable ones showed Ok in the Property grid and all went OK.
Today, I added some others, and from that point, it makes the designer bombs.
Initially, the (presumably) offending property was "new DisplayMember" which referenced in the set and get methods the base.DisplayMember. Suspecting that was the mistake, I changed it to "public string DisplayProperty", to avoid name clash, but the error continued. 
Ultimately, I also set a private variable displayProperty, and set the base.DisplayMember in the OnCreateControl event. 
Nothing works.
Any help will be appreciated. 
If it´s required, I could put the code, but it´s very big. 
TIA
EDIT: looking at the Application events, they show the VS failures, but don´t tells anything regarding the error.

Comment: Have you done a complete rebuild of the solution? In some cases I'd seen controls error due to version/dependency mismatches. Barring that, start by removing suspect properties. Faced with things like this the first step is to revert back to the previous working state, verify that it is working, then add back in the new state incrementally until you identify exactly where/what caused the crash. From that you can either find the solution or narrow down your question here.

Comment: I´ll do that. Thank you

Comment: Hours chasing a phantom. Look my answer...

Answer (score 0):

I had a property that looked like

```
        bool autoComplete = true;

    [Category("Autocomplete")]
    [Description("This is the only property of this group to set. All others will be set accordingly.")]
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)]
    public bool AutoComplete
    {
        get { return AutoComplete;  }
        set { autoComplete = value; }
    }
```

See the capital A in the get procedure... once in the designer, recursive calls ended in a stack overflow. But none of this were explicit in the event log.
Hours chasing a phantom.

Comment: Ah yeah, aren't those Gems!  :)